# iframe widget facebook timeline responsive

Tags: html, css

i have this line of html code from a iframe timeline, i want to make this iframe responsive , this is my css code and the iframe code, when i apply the code when the browser resizes, only half of the iframe window appear.

what can be? , i need to apply the property data-width?

```
 iframe{
        padding-top: 0.5%;
        width: 40%;
        height: 394px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 12px !important;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 12px !important;
        border-top-left-radius: 12px !important;
        border-top-right-radius: 12px !important;
    }

     <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FCl%25C3%25ADnica-Materno-Infantil-Casa-Del-Ni%25C3%25B1o-SA-399571326824453%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

i used width: 100% and created col-md-4 class and done.